# How do I make a formatted formula that includes text?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know my question might be confusing, I really didn't know how to word it. but ill describe my problem. So I have a formula that calculates miles per gallon and then it adds "Miles per gal" to the end of the formula

`=(D13-D14)/C13 &" Miles per gal"` output> `20.1363636363636 Miles per gal`

My problem is I don't want all those decimals I would want it to be `20.14 Miles per gal`. So how would I make the output of the equation roundup to the 100th decimal point?

---

Edit: and another thing but I don't know if this is even possible. but is it possible to have the number and the text output different fonts sizes?

so output would ([image])

"20.14" = Font 15 "Miles per gal" = Font 10

Comment: There's `ROUND()`,`CEILING()`,`FLOOR()`. Take your pick

Comment: If you want different fonts, you'll need to have the numeric portion in one column and the label "Miles per gal" (or "mpg") in the column to the right. You can then size columns as you like and apply different formatting. Depending on your application (which we can't see), you could also turn of gridlines (View > Gridlines > uncheck) and apply alternate-row coloring for visual separation of rows, which would cause the number and label to appear side-by-side without barriers as one unit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have multiple formats in a calculated cell.

Try this:

`=ROUND((D13-D14)/C13, 2) & " Miles per gal"`

The second parameter of the round function is how many decimal places, you can adjust it to as many or few as you like.